# How do you subscribe to Recurly.js checkout pricing events in React?

Tags: reactjs, recurly

I'm trying to create a payment screen in React using [Recurly.js](https://developers.recurly.com/reference/recurly-js). I'm using the official [React library](https://github.com/recurly/react-recurly) and am trying to hook into the `set.plan` event to retrieve plan information. I previously did this without issue using vanilla Recurly.js in Angular, but I haven't been able to do so in React and it's not clear to me if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a bug.

I adapted one of the [Interactive Demo](https://recurly.github.io/react-recurly/?path=/docs/introduction-interactive-demo--page) scenarios to demonstrate this. Please see the comments added in [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recurly-js-plan-info-7ndjz?file=/src/checkout-pricing.js:1115-1589):

```
const [{ price, loading }, setPricing, checkoutPricing] = useCheckoutPricing(
  null,
  setRecurlyError
);

useEffect(() => {
  /*
    Should this be called frequently? I know the price state gets updated, but I would not
    expect to constantly receive a new/updated instance of checkoutPricing.
  */
  console.log("checkoutPricing updated", checkoutPricing);

  /*
    This never gets called even after selecting a new plan in the dropdown menu
    */
  checkoutPricing.on("set.plan", (plan) => {
    console.log("plan updated", plan);
  });
}, [checkoutPricing]);
```

Am I getting a new instance of checkoutPricing on each render? That might explain why my event is never firing, but I'm not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @cfnerd Recurly support was beyond painful to deal with, but after more than a month they acknowledged there's an issue with the React library. They submitted the feedback to their product team but made no commitment to fixing it.